# Corda Node: Standalone Artemis server AMQ214016: Failed to create netty connection

Tags: corda, activemq-artemis

We're trying to connect a Corda node to a standalone Artemis server as described in [the Corda documentation](https://docs.corda.r3.com/corda-firewall-component.html#standalone-artemis-server). After starting the Corda node we get below error

```
[ERROR] 2019-07-03T11:47:45,410Z [main] core.client.createConnection - AMQ214016: Failed to create netty connection [errorCode=v108q1, moreInformationAt=https://errors.corda.net/OS/4.0/v108q1]
io.netty.handler.ssl.NotSslRecordException: not an SSL/TLS record: 485454502f312e312034303020496c6c6567616c2063686172616374657220307831360d0a436f6e74656e742d547970653sdfeqwerfsad46d6c3dfsdsfb636861727365743d69736f2d383835392d310d0a436f6e74656e742d4c656e6774683a2036350d0a436f6e6e656374696f6e3a20636c6f73650d0a0d0a3c68313e426164204d65737330303c2f68313e3c7072653e726561736f6e3a20496c6c6567616c2063686172616374657220307831363c2f7072653e
    at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.decodeJdkCompatible(SslHandler.java:1138) ~[netty-handler-4.1.22.Final.jar:4.1.22.Final]
    at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.decode(SslHandler.java:1203) ~[netty-handler-4.1.22.Final.jar:4.1.22.Final]
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.decodeRemovalReentryProtection(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:489) ~[netty-codec-4.1.22.Final.jar:4.1.22.Final]
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.callDecode(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:428) ~[netty-codec-4.1.22.Final.jar:4.1.22.Final]
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:265) ~[netty-codec-4.1.22.Final.jar:4.1.22.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:362) ~[netty-transport-4.1.22.Final.jar:4.1.22.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:348) ~[netty-transport-4.1.22.Final.jar:4.1.22.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:340) ~[netty-transport-4.1.22.Final.jar:4.1.22.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.channelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1414) ~[netty-transport-4.1.22.Final.jar:4.1.22.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:362) ~[netty-transport-4.1.22.Final.jar:4.1.22.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:348) ~[netty-transport-4.1.22.Final.jar:4.1.22.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:945) ~[netty-transport-4.1.22.Final.jar:4.1.22.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.epoll.AbstractEpollStreamChannel$EpollStreamUnsafe.epollInReady(AbstractEpollStreamChannel.java:806) ~[netty-transport-native-epoll-4.1.22.Final-linux-x86_64.jar:4.1.22.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.epoll.EpollEventLoop.processReady(EpollEventLoop.java:404) ~[netty-transport-native-epoll-4.1.22.Final-linux-x86_64.jar:4.1.22.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.epoll.EpollEventLoop.run(EpollEventLoop.java:304) ~[netty-transport-native-epoll-4.1.22.Final-linux-x86_64.jar:4.1.22.Final]
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$5.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:886) ~[netty-common-4.1.22.Final.jar:4.1.22.Final]
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.utils.ActiveMQThreadFactory$1.run(ActiveMQThreadFactory.java:118) ~[artemis-commons-2.6.2.jar:2.6.2]
```

We're using this in the Corda node conf file:

```
messagingServerAddress="xx.xxx.xx.xxxx:5672"
messagingServerExternal=true
```

We've configured this acceptor in the Artemis `broker.xml`:

```xml
<acceptors>
   <acceptor name="amqp">tcp://xx.xx.xx.xx::5672?tcpSendBufferSize=1048576;tcpReceiveBufferSize=1048576;protocols=AMQP;useEpoll=true;amqpCredits=1000;amqpLowCredits=300</acceptor>
</acceptors>
```

Comment: At Stack Overflow when comments ask for clarification it's best practice to modify your question and add the requested details so the question is more comprehensive and clear for everyone without having to read all the comments. I've edited your question myself to add the details you've provided.

Answer (score 0):

This issue is an SSL problem between the Artemis connection. There are some docs on how to properly do it, take a look at them here: https://docs.corda.net/docs/corda-os/4.5/node-services.html#artemismessagingserver

There are a few other articles in the docs on getting Artemis to work correctly.

I would also say that this is something you'd have an easier time trying to work out with the enterprise support team as it's tricky to work out on your own.

good luck!